# appgyver steroids tint color of navigation bar does not work for Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, cordova, steroids

I'm building an app with [AppGyver Steroids](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids/) and would like to change the color of the navigation bar. After a short search I found this in the [Documentation](https://academy.appgyver.com/categories/3-user-interface-and-design/contents/16-customizing-navigation-bar-appearance) so I changed

```
steroids.config.navigationBar.tintColor = "#FFCC22"
```

in the CoffeeScript file. Unfortunately I cannot get it to work on Android `4.1.2`

Is there any know issues, or isn't it working for Android < KitKat?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The AppGyver Android runtime does not support styling via application.coffee (the guide you linked has actually been changed to reflect this). For further examples, see the related forum thread [here](https://forums.appgyver.com/#!/steroids-native-ui:steroids-tint-color-of-navi).

In short, to style your navigation bar, add the following to `www/native-styles/android.css`:

```
navigation-bar {
  background-color: #FFCC22;
}
```